# How to create custom action for Jenkins in AWS CodePipeline using Terraform

Tags: jenkins, terraform, aws-codebuild

How can I create custom action in CodeBuild using Terraform?

I want to define CodePipeline with two stages: Source and Test. While Source is clear, I'm having problem with Test stage.

I defined action like:

```
action {
  name = "Jenkins"
  category = "Test"
  owner = "Custom"
  provider = "Jenkins"
  version = "1"
  input_artifacts = ["source_output"]
  output_artifacts = ["build_output"]
  configuration = {
    ProjectName = "MyProject"
  }
}
```

And `terraform apply` fails with message that action is not defined. When I define action either in the console or using AWS CLI (`aws codepipeline create-custom-action-type ...`) then my terraform apply completes with success.

I was not able to find a way how to define custom action in terraform. Any ideas how to do it?
I'd like to avoid additional steps outside my terraform code...

Comment: Did you ever find out how?

Comment: @alonisser Unfortunately no, I left it with action defined by AWS CLI like mentioned above.